# Target a specific class in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to grab the div `ing` out of the specific list element that is clicked on to do other things with it. This is what I have. It's not working.

CSS

```
  .ing{
   display:none;
  }
```

HTML

```
<ul class="grid">
   <li onclick="openModal()">
      <a href="">
         <img src="" >
         <h3>Easy Crock Pot Recipe</h3>
         <h4>crockpot</h4>
      </a>
      <div class="ing">ingredient</div>
   </li>
   <li onclick="openModal()">
      <a href="">
         <img src="" >
         <h3>Chocolate Chip Cookie Bars</h3>
         <h4>diabetic</h4>
      </a>
      <div class="ing">dough</div>
   </li>
   <li onclick="openModal()">
      <a href="">
         <img src="" >
         <h3>Onion Meatloaf</h3>
         <h4>meatloaf with sauce</h4>
      </a>
      <div class="ing">meatloaf</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
    function openModal() {
        $(this).find(".ing").show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong reference to this in your js code. Change your `li` code to pass a reference to current element like `<li onclick="openModal(this)">` and then change your js function to something like below

```
function openModal(that) {
   $(that).find(".ing").show();
 }
```

And as you are using jQuery here, ideally you should remove the onclick from your html altogether and change your js code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find(".ing").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Also needs to close function with `}` and aslo need to properly close the last li with `</li>`